# uploading an indefinite number of cards onto home page of a website

Tags: html, css, backend

i am having some trouble with the frontend logic of a project i am currently working on. i am fairly new to html, so i am not sure what exactly is possible here.

my project takes a singular input and returns whatever relevant information is in my database through the form of an html card class.

however, i am struggling to understand how i can upload an undisclosed amount of cards to my frontend. would i create a class called card and then run a for loop that inputs the information needed? please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>tabs prototype</title>
    <link rel="styelsheet" href ="./cards.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
</head>

<body>
    <!-- our array of images -->
   <div class="cards">

    <!-- ****would we create a loop here?-->

    <!-- our singular image -->
    <div class="card">

        <!-- our image, placeholder is here for now -->
        <img src="./images/butterfly.jpg" alt="" class="card__image">
        
        <!-- random words, we can probably remove this but for the sake of proof of concept it's here rn -->
        <div class="car__content">
            <p>item description</p>
        </div>
       
        <!-- how many people liked the image -->
        <div class="card__info">
            <div>
                <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                    favorite
                    </span>5
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do or what the code you posted has to do with it. Please clarify

Comment: You would use a scripting language, such as PHP and PDO to connect to the database and fetch the relevant information, then use a `foreach` loop to loop through the results and print each card.

Comment: @timgavin, thank you i was thinking that i might have to switch over to php, but was unsure on whether it would be possible with html. do you know any resources where i could familiarize myself with this function?

Comment: wrap the card div with a loop referencing each element in loop to prefill each card with details from your database

Comment: @butterflyrunner PHP and HTML go together like peanut butter and chocolate; they're made for each other. There are literally thousands of tutorials on PHP, this is a good one: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLr3d3QYzkw2xabQRUpcZ_IBk9W50M9pe-